# How to refer to the count of items in a Sencha Touch XTemplate?

Tags: templates, sencha-touch

I have a sencha template for a data view like the following, where I would like to insert the current number of items in the store. How can I refer to this value in the template or xtemplate?

```
tpl: "<div class='itineraryCount'>{{count would go here}} entries</div>"
```

I've tried the API documentation for XTemplate but can't seem to find what I am looking for. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to using a `DataView` rather than a plain `Panel` to show your count, then you can take advantage of the count value being updated as the store changes automatically, and you can just drop in the length of the `values` array into your XTemplate:

```
new Ext.DataView({
    store: YOUR_STORE,
    tpl: '<div>{[values.length]}</div>',
    itemSelector:'.item',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm from 2020 and in extjs v.6 in the docs I can see following:

> There are some special variables available:
>
> ...
>
> xindex: If you are in a "for" or "foreach" looping template, the index
>   of the loop you are in (1-based).
>
> xcount: If you are in a "for" looping template, the total length of
>   the array you are looping.

So, now you can use something like this (if you are in a "for" or "foreach" loop):

```
tpl: "<div class='itineraryCount'>{[xcount]} entries</div>"
```